# OpenCV 4.5 Error: Assertion failed (fabs(wsum[j]) >= 0) in cv::opt_AVX2::`anonymous-namespace'::BilateralFilter_32f_Invoker::operator

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am fairly new to openCv and am trying to perform bilateral filtering on a 3 channel, 32 floating point image.
However, every time it runs it throws this exception in a loop until the program crashes.

This seems to be the only openCv function that causes this. I am able to perform other functions such as blur() or GaussianBlur() without issue.

The error:

> Assertion failed (fabs(wsum[j]) >= 0) in
> cv::opt_AVX2::`anonymous-namespace'::BilateralFilter_32f_Invoker::operator

Current code, I am grabbing the image out of a bitmap and converting to an openCV matrix.

```
cv::Mat im1 = img1->getMat();
cv::Mat im2 = img2->getMat();
cv::Mat filter1;
cv::Mat filter2;
try {

    cv::bilateralFilter(im1, filter1, 3, 3.0, 3.0);
    cv::bilateralFilter(im2, filter2, 3, 3.0, 3.0);

    filter1.copyTo(im1);
    filter2.copyTo(im2);

}
catch(exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "An exception occurred " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: are `im1` and `im2` proper images, or are they empty? you call `getMat`... check that this succeeded.

Comment: They seem to be fine upon inspection with imshow, I am also running GaussianBlur() on im1 further down in the code without issue.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/cv-bilateralfilter-assertion-fails-with-3-channel-float/8176

Comment: what's the minimal and maximal value in your input? are any values inf or NaN? with generated dummy content (normal distribution of values), I can't replicate this. can you replicate this if you **don't** use `getMat`, on whatever `img1` is, but when you use some other way to create those Mats?

Comment: Upon manual inspection, there are NaN values in my matrix. I'm going to assume this is causing this problem, weird I never noticed as the final output images look fine - Thanks.